# How to implement angular.js retry with exponential back-off?

Tags: angularjs

How would I implement retry logic in angular.js with exponential back-off?

1. Would the right place for the logic be in $httpProvider.requestInterceptors?
2. Can I selectively pick to use it with some $http services and not others?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post, but here's my thoughts.  I'd use a `responseInterceptor`.  Since you can just return another promise, you can decide how to retry.  You have access the the $http `config` in the interceptor, so you can add special configuration to determine what the back-off should be (or whether to apply the retry logic at all).

Answer (score 1):

For upcoming people: Using some pre available components and module seems more Angular. So you can try one of these [backo2](https://libraries.io/npm/backo2) or [angular-backoff](https://github.com/fraserxu/angular-backoff)

There usage is given on each link. However don't use setTimeout its not so Angular and you should use $interval or $timeout.